# using macros for equal and and operators

Tags: c

Recently refreshed my self on C language. From some of the blogs, i have read operators such as "==" and '&&' lead to error prone where programmers use '=' and '&' respectively, instead , and programmers spent lot of time to find and fix the issues.

i think that defining macros for "==" and "&&"  will solve the issue.

```
#define EQ ==
#define AND &&

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 1 , b = 2 ; 

    if(a EQ 1 AND b EQ 2 ){
        //  some statements
    }

}
```

is it clutter the readability ? is there any other solution to solve this issue ?

Comment: the best way to solve this kind of problems is to get better programmers who're experienced in programming(in general and C in particular). Any half decent C/C++/Java/C#/Javascript programmer knows = standard for assignment and == for test-of-equality. Substituting string tokens for operators adds to unreadability for other programmers. Stick to standard language operators.

Comment: For the equality operator: put the number literal on the left hand side so if `==` is mistyped as `=`, a compilation error is raised.

Comment: @timrau not always, is the other side of the equality sign a constant

Comment: @timrau: That's really not useful. All modern compilers have a warning for assignments used as truth values, and almost everybody turns on that warning.

Comment: `and` is already a synonym for `&&` without using the preprocessor.

Comment: When two values are compared for equality I **expect** to see `==`. Seeing `EQU`, frankly, would really start to get on my nerves quickly.

Comment: Almost 80-85% of C code, even today is C89. @JasonD

Comment: @timrau: Writing `if (5 == x)` can mitigate the risk, but personally I find it *ugly*. Such expressions have been referred to as [Yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Comment: @JasonD: `and` is a macro defined in `<iso646.h>`. (It's available in C++ without `#include`ing a header, but not in C.)

Comment: @KeithThompson true, I was thinking C++. Still, if someone wanted to do this, they'd be better off including that header, rather than making their own #defines. (though I think they'd be even better off, not doing it at all).

Comment: @JasonD: Except that there's no macro or alternative token for `==`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Also true. I just wanted to point out that it was at least partially re-inventing the wheel, not to suggest that it was a good idea.

Comment: in particular, when invoked with ´-Wall´, the gcc will show the warning `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` which should tip you off if anything is wrong in that specific line. having readable code formatting helps as well.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer not to touch the very fundamental syntax of the language, like creating macros to replace C keywords or operators.

In this case it is pretty simple, and may not alter much the readability, but other programmers (if you are not the only one maintaining the code) seeing those macros may be tempted to create other macros for something else they *think* is ambiguous or error prone.

So I would not endorse macros at the keywords / operators level in C.
But you may use some compiler options to show when there is an ambiguity, like

```
  gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog
```

having `Wall` enabling all warnings (you can refine the warnings with gcc). This depends upon the compiler you are using.

For instance

```
  int a=1,b=2;
  if (a = b) { ... }
```

would give a warning having gcc as compiler with the `-Wall` option.

Answer (score 1):

that's a bad idea
the best thing to do is compile with all warning flags activated (-Wall) and make sure that you can compile your code without warnings

and TDD. It's more about practices that the syntax

I would recommend the book "Code Complete"

Comment: +1 for -Wall. Also I recommend using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=<your preferred C standard>`

Comment: There is nothing in the original question indicating that the OP is even using GCC. So this definitely does not deserve any upvotes, stack overflow isn't some GCC forum.

Comment: I see your point. Nevertheless I explicitly said what to do (set all warning flags). In parentheses I just typed the way to do it in GCC, without thinking about it twice. But IMHO the point is: it is not only about replying whether is a bad idea or not, but also pointing out what would be/is a proper way to do things. Moreover, my impression is, anyone with some C experience has come across GCC at some point. But I could be wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

To attempt to re-define the C language is always a very bad idea. To replace operators through macros will make the code unreadable to other C programmers.

Regarding && accidentally turning into &, I doubt it is an issue, at least I have never encountered that problem. There is already alternative logical operators in standard C, you should use those if anything.

> The header `<iso646.h>` defines the following eleven macros (on the
>   left) that expand to the corresponding tokens (on the right):

```
and     &&
and_eq  &=
bitand  &
bitor   |
compl   ~
not     !
not_eq  !=
or      ||
or_eq   |=
xor     ^
xor_eq  ^=
```

The idea of == being dangerous is a terribly old-fashioned idea. In the 80s, confused programmers invented obscure rules like "always put the literal in front of the variable when doing comparison", i.e `if (0 == var)`.

The correct way to avoid bugs related to this is to avoid assignment inside conditions. Once you have adopted that as good coding style, dodging such bugs is easy. To spot them has been a non-issue since the release of Turbo C in 1990. Since then, pretty much every single compiler has been able to warn for "possibly incorrect assignment" when you made an assignment inside an if statement.

In modern programming, all professional programmers use static analyser tools to spot all kinds of compile time bugs. If your compiler for some reason is unable to spot this bug, then the static analyser certainly will.

So to answer your question: yes it is clutter and makes the code more error-prone and less readable.

Comment: `<iso646.h>` doesn't provide an alternative for `==`. Its purpose is not to provide readable alternatives; it's to make things easier on systems with limited character sets (something that's probably not much of an issue these days).

Comment: @KeithThompson I know. Clarified the answer by changing the text to "There is already alternative logical operators".

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a particularly good idea. It means that any experienced C programmer reading your code has to find out what `EQ` and `AND` mean before he can read your code.

Sure, `==` can be error-prone, but IMHO the best solution to that problem is to (a) turn on warnings in your compiler, and (b) *be careful*.

(The standard header `<iso646.h>` provides a macro `and` that expands to `&&`, but it doesn't provide a macro for `==`. The point of `<iso646.h>` was to support systems on which certain characters are difficult to use due to old national variant character sets, not to provide more readable alternatives.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think there is a problem here. Any modern compiler will issue a warning if something fishy will be detected.